# What Character encoding is this?

Tags: blackberry

When i backup my blackberry using blackberry desktop mananger, it saves it as an .ipd file.
its in hex... Not sure if its any particular type. But i used software called ABC amber Text Converter to convert this .ipd file into plain text format. And some of it comes out as plain text, Like all the messages saved in the backup file. But some of the text in the file looks like this:

qÖ²u_+;¢õ¿B[[¤†D`Ø,>p
|Cñ:ÌQ†nÁä¼sÒ®sKDv©{(]
)++³É«.gsn>
z
'‚51o4Kq
8Ütâ¯cí¿þ2´Õ|5kl$S,H
dbiIjz
*!~k$|
&*OÝ>0ðî­wã
+zno%q
2k;
YnÁÅŸ5|Xñ7Ú<}y2
A
VÜ‰lO5‰<œtÅRI-I

Does anybody have any idea What the hell this is or if there is Any way i can decode this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's just binary data. You may have been able to extract some text from the file where strings of text were stored, but the rest will be just bytes of data.

You'll need a specific program that understands these backup files. A quick google reveals a few choices, such as MagicBerry.

One of the Blackberry developers has helpfully blogged a bit of information about the binary format, so you could try using that to write your own program to parse it:

http://us.blackberry.com/devjournals/resources/journals/jan_2006/ipd_file_format.jsp

Comment: Thank for the reply, yea i have the software:) but im doing my own personal little project the parse these files just like the software does, and wanted to know if these strange characters contained any important information! Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated my answer with a link to a brief description of the binary format, which might help you to get started.